# Kappa coefficient for variable number of raters

Tags: agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I want to calculate the Inter-rater Reliability of an annotated dataset, where the number of raters for each subject is variable (3-5 raters) and subjects can be annotated with one of 7 categories.

Cohen's kappa is not applicable since it requires exactly 2 raters. Also, Fleiss's kappa is not applicable as it requires the exact number of raters for each subject. I've read about the generalized kappa by Uebersax (1982) and it seems to be the most suitable solution. However, I didn't find any implementation or tool for calculating the generalized kappa.

Comment: Should we assume you’re looking for a recommendation other than “Implement the formula from Uebersax”?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy No. Either other recommendation or implemented formula will be good. I edited the question.

Comment: If you're looking for a software implementation, what platform do you want? R? MATLAB? Python? Excel?

Comment: Thanks @JeffreyGirard! I prefer Python or Excel.

Comment: Check out https://agreestat.com/ there are excel and cloud based implementations.

Comment: @JeffreyGirard Thank you, but I don't an implementation suitable for my case.

Comment: Ok if you can use R there are many solutions.